# Forcefully trigger a rule in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-rules

How do I force a rule to be triggered in Drupal, for example from code?

Comment: Do you mean how to invoke a hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by *rule* you mean an *action* (usually invoked via triggers), take a look at the [actions_do()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/actions_do/6) function.